# How to apply a closure which takes row and column indices over all chars in a string in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, closures, borrow-checker

I'm trying to parse a multi-line string. Every line has the same length and the chars of the string represent numeric values on a field. I want to map these to an 2d array of `u8` values. I also need to keep track of a point marked as 'P' in the input.

I went for iterating over the whole string and applying a `char_parse` closure to every character in the string. This closure captures a mutable reference to a `point` variable to extract the point while mapping all characters to numbers. To extract the point though the closure needs access to the current row and column of a given character. When enumerating lines and characters to pass row and col indices to the closure the compiler complains that a "captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body".

My code so far:

```rust
use ndarray::{Array1, Array2};
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Point2D {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Field {
    heights: Array2<u8>,
    point: Point2D,
}

impl FromStr for Field {
    type Err = String;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let mut lines = s.lines().peekable();
        let cols = lines.peek().ok_or("No input")?.len();

        let mut point: Option<Point2D> = None;

        let mut char_parse = |(row, col), chr| match chr {
            c if c.is_ascii_lowercase() => Ok((c as u8) - 97),
            'P' => match point {
                Some(_) => Err("Duplicate point"),
                None => {
                    point = Some(Point2D { x: col, y: row });
                    Ok(0)
                }
            },
            _ => Err("Unsupported symbol"),
        };

        // This does not compile:
        let flat_heights: Array1<u8> = lines
            .enumerate()
            .flat_map(|(row, line)| {
                line.chars()
                    .enumerate()
                    .map(|(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
            })
            .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;

        let rows = flat_heights.len() / cols;

        let heights = flat_heights.into_shape((rows, cols)).map_err(|_| "Invalid shape")?;
        let point = point.ok_or("No point found")?;

        Ok(Field { heights, point })
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use ndarray::array;

    #[test]
    fn parse_heights() {
        let field: Result<Field, _> = "cab\nabP\nacc".parse();
        assert_eq!(
            field,
            Ok(Field {
                heights: array![[2, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 2],],
                point: Point2D { x: 2, y: 1 },
            })
        );
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about a capturing variable escaping the closure:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/question.rs:40:17
   |
24 |           let mut char_parse = |(row, col), chr| match chr {
   |               -------------- variable defined here
...
39 |               .flat_map(|(row, line)| {
   |                                     - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
40 | /                 line.chars()
41 | |                     .enumerate()
42 | |                     .map(|(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
   | |_______________________________________----------_________________^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |                                         |
   |                                         variable captured here
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `row`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/question.rs:42:26
   |
42 |                     .map(|(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^             --- `row` is borrowed here
   |                          |
   |                          may outlive borrowed value `row`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/question.rs:40:17
   |
40 | /                 line.chars()
41 | |                     .enumerate()
42 | |                     .map(|(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
   | |__________________________________________________________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `row` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
42 |                     .map(move |(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
   |                          ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
```

But when adding that `move` the compiler complains that the closure must implement `Copy`:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `char_parse`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/question.rs:42:26
   |
24 |         let mut char_parse = |(row, col), chr| match chr {
   |             -------------- captured outer variable
...
39 |             .flat_map(|(row, line)| {
   |                       ------------- captured by this `FnMut` closure
...
42 |                     .map(move |(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----------
   |                          |                 |
   |                          |                 variable moved due to use in closure
   |                          |                 move occurs because `char_parse` has type `[closure@src/question.rs:24:30: 24:47]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                          move out of `char_parse` occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

How would one get around this error? Is this the idiomatic way to do this? It would probably work to only use a single map over the whole string (and calculate row/col on the go) but is that the right approach?

Side question: Why does the `char_parse` closure have to be `mut`? AFAICT the references it captures don't change (is this bc. of interior mutability of those captured references?)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `move` is the correct thing to do. The problem is that when you add `move` you are moving all captured variables, and you only want to move `row` and leave `char_parse` borrowed.

The solution is to do `let char_parse = &mut char_parse;` before the inner closure, now, we're moving, but we're only moving a reference to `char_parse`.

However, now you will get a new error:

```rust
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/lib.rs:42:17
   |
25 |           let mut char_parse = |(row, col), chr| match chr {
   |               -------------- variable defined here
...
40 |               .flat_map(|(row, line)| {
   |                                     - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
41 |                   let char_parse = &mut char_parse;
   |                                         ---------- variable captured here
42 | /                 line.chars()
43 | |                     .enumerate()
44 | |                     .map(move |(col, chr)| char_parse((row, col), chr))
   | |_______________________________________________________________________^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

Exactly as the error says, you cannot return a reference to a closure that captures `char_reference` by reference from a `FnMut` closure. This is because we can call the outer closure twice, yielding two closures that both concurrently have a mutable reference to `char_parse`, violating the borrow rules.

To fix that we need to capture `char_parse` by shared reference. However, trying to do that yields an error as it needs to mutate the captured `point`. We need to use interior mutability:

```rust
let point = std::cell::Cell::new(None);

let char_parse = |(row, col), chr| match chr {
    c if c.is_ascii_lowercase() => Ok((c as u8) - 97),
    'P' => match point.get() {
        Some(_) => Err("Duplicate point"),
        None => {
            point.set(Some(Point2D { x: col, y: row }));
            Ok(0)
        }
    },
    _ => Err("Unsupported symbol"),
};

// ...

let point = point.get().ok_or("No point found")?;
```

Now we can do `let char_parse = &char_parse;` (or `let char_parse = char_parse.clone();`) and it will work.